# query related has_many model in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models `User` And `Service`. `User` has_and_belongs_to_many `Services` same goes for `Services`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I need to find all users who provide selected services. Something like:

> @users = User.where(:services_ids => [2,3,4])

Comment: Did you create the join table?

Comment: @Zambon yes i have a join table

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
User.join(:services).where(:services.id => [2,3,4]).uniq
```

Comment: this will create a duplicate users if a user has services 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@users = Service.where(:id => [2,3,4])).map{|svc| svc.users}.uniq.flatten
```

or

```
@users = User.all(:include => :services, :conditions => ["services.id in ?", (2,3,4)])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for a quick reply, it throws an error: undefined local variable or method `users`

Comment: Please include your models in the question.